# Calculate gap between two datasets (pandas, matplotlib, fill_between already used)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'd like to ask for suggestions how to calculate lenght of gap between two datasets in matplotlib made of pandas dataframe. Ideally, I would like to have these gap values written in the plot and also, if it is possible, include them into the dataframe.
Here is my simplified example of dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Mean-1': [0.195842, 0.295069, 0.321345, 0.773725], 'SEM-1': [0.001216, 0.002687, 0.005267, 0.029974], 'Mean-2': [0.143103, 0.250505, 0.305767, 0.960804],'SEM-2': [0.000959, 0.001368, 0.003722, 0.150025], 'Atom Number': [1, 3, 5, 7]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    Mean-1      SEM-1       Mean-2      SEM-2     Atom Number
0   0.195842    0.001216    0.143103    0.000959    1
1   0.295069    0.002687    0.250505    0.001368    3
2   0.321345    0.005267    0.305767    0.003722    5
3   0.773725    0.029974    0.960804    0.150025    7
```

Then I made plot, where we can see two lines representing Mean-1 and Mean-2, and then shaded area around each line representing standard error of the mean. This is done for the selected atom numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.plot(x='Atom Number', y=['Mean-1','Mean-2'])

y_1 = df['Mean-1']
y_2 = df['Mean-2']
x = df['Atom Number']

error_1 = df['SEM-1']
error_2 = df['SEM-1']

ax.fill_between(df['Atom Number'], y_1-error_1, y_1+error_1, alpha=0.2, edgecolor='#CC4F1B', facecolor='#FF9848')
ax.fill_between(df['Atom Number'], y_2-error_2, y_2+error_2, alpha=0.2, edgecolor='#3F7F4C', facecolor='#7EFF99')
plt.xticks(x)
```

[image]

What I would like to do further is to calculate the gap for each residue. **The gap is** the white space only, thus **space where the lines as well as the shaded areas (SEMs) don't overlap**.
And also would like to know if I can somehow print the gap values from the plot? And save them into column. Thank You for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a compact solution but you could try something like this (Check the order of things). Calculate all the position (`y_i` and upper and lower limits).

```
import numpy as np
df['y1_upper'] = y_1+error_1
df['y1_lower'] = y_1-error_1
df['y2_upper'] = y_2+error_2
df['y2_lower'] = y_2-error_2
```

which gives

```
    Mean-1     SEM-1    Mean-2     SEM-2  Atom Number  y1_upper  y1_lower  \
0  0.195842  0.001216  0.143103  0.000959            1  0.197058  0.194626   
1  0.295069  0.002687  0.250505  0.001368            3  0.297756  0.292382   
2  0.321345  0.005267  0.305767  0.003722            5  0.326612  0.316078   
3  0.773725  0.029974  0.960804  0.150025            7  0.803699  0.743751   

   y2_upper  y2_lower     
0  0.144319  0.141887  
1  0.253192  0.247818  
2  0.311034  0.300500  
3  0.990778  0.930830
```

The distances (gaps) are calculated differently depending on if `y_1` is over `y_2`and vice versa. So use conditions on the upper and lower limits and use `linalg.norm` to compute the distance.

```
conditions = [
    (df['y1_lower'] >= df['y2_upper']),
    (df['y1_lower'] < df['y2_upper'])]
choices = [np.linalg.norm(df['y1_lower']-df['y2_upper']), np.linalg.norm(df['y2_lower']-df['y1_upper'])]
df['dist'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

This gives

```
    Mean-1     SEM-1    Mean-2     SEM-2  Atom Number  y1_upper  y1_lower  \
0  0.195842  0.001216  0.143103  0.000959            1  0.197058  0.194626   
1  0.295069  0.002687  0.250505  0.001368            3  0.297756  0.292382   
2  0.321345  0.005267  0.305767  0.003722            5  0.326612  0.316078   
3  0.773725  0.029974  0.960804  0.150025            7  0.803699  0.743751   

   y2_upper  y2_lower      dist  
0  0.144319  0.141887  0.255175  
1  0.253192  0.247818  0.255175  
2  0.311034  0.300500  0.255175  
3  0.990778  0.930830  0.149605
```

As I said, check the order, but this is a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, do you want something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = df.plot(x='Atom Number', y=['Mean-1','Mean-2'], figsize=(15,8))

y_1 = df['Mean-1']
y_2 = df['Mean-2']
x = df['Atom Number']

error_1 = df['SEM-1']
error_2 = df['SEM-1']

ax.fill_between(df['Atom Number'], y_1-error_1, y_1+error_1, alpha=0.2, edgecolor='#CC4F1B', facecolor='#FF9848')
ax.fill_between(df['Atom Number'], y_2-error_2, y_2+error_2, alpha=0.2, edgecolor='#3F7F4C', facecolor='#7EFF99')
ax.fill_between(df['Atom Number'], y_1+error_1, y_2-error_2, alpha=.2, edgecolor='k', facecolor='blue')

for i in range(len(x)):
    gap = y_1[i]+error_1[i] - y_2[i]-error_2[i]
    ylabel = min(y_1[i], y_2[i]) + abs(gap) / 2
    _ = ax.annotate(f'{gap:0.4f}', xy=(x[i],ylabel), xytext=(x[i]-.14,y_1[i]+gap/abs(gap)*.2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"))
plt.xticks(x);
```

Output:

[image]